# Crystal Reports XI: Suppressing a section using defined Parameter values

Tags: crystal-reports

My report is a letter confirming information we have taken from a customer. The information is based on date values, so a start and end date.

I have added a parameter which gives the options of where the information was gathered, so either the Website or over the Phone.

I also have a formula which determines whether the start and end dates given are equal.

The report has 4 page header sections with different text, one for each of the data gathered over the phone, and one for each where the data was gather via the Website.
I want to suppress these accordingly using the Section Expert, and what I have done is tick the "Suppress" box and added the following formula:

`({@parameter} = "Web" and ({@formula}) = "1"`

I want this to suppress the section where the Parameter is "Web" and the formula determines that the start and end date are the same.

The following sections have the other variations i.e.

```
({@parameter} = "Phone" and ({@formula}) = "1"
({@parameter} = "Web" and ({@formula}) = "0"
({@parameter} = "Phone" and ({@formula}) = "0"
```

This unfortunately does not give me the desired result, although the formula works when I only have one or the other of the criteria, e.g. only ({@parameter} = "Phone" *or only* ({@formula}) = "1"

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Check your brackets - they're not closed correctly in your example.  In fact, you probably don't need them here:
  {@parameter} = "Phone" and {@formula} = "1"

Comment: display the value {?parameter} and {@formula} in report and see if the expected values are coming while selecting the different parameter value.

Comment: @Pinwar13, I had tried that already and yes, it displayed the expected values for both the Parameter and Formula

Comment: @tequila2k That was it. Thank you so much. I knew it would be simple... Appreciate your help.